# Linear gradient not showing when using percentages in Chrome v90

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a gradient

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #333, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4))
```

that worked perfectly fine and still works in every browser but chrome v90 (90.0.4430.212). When i remove percentages, gradient will become visible but it's not the same looking as with percentages.

From MDN docs it looks like my gradient should be valid ([linear-gradient)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient())

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong? I have no idea how to fix this in chrome.

Comment: show us what looking do you expect to see

Comment: I expect to see a gradient but instead i see nothing in chrome. This very simple sandbox illustrates issue. In chrome gradient div displays nothing, in other browser it shows a gradient background. https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-lederberg-nyybv?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: it's works fine for me and I have the same chrome version as you

Comment: After a windows update and restart it looks like working for me too. I have not seen it happen before. Very strange. Thank you for help